# Passing data to another screen with Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I'm trying to pass the data to another screen using `Provider`, but it seems I'm always passing on the same data unless I sort the List and then pass the different data (meaning I'm probably switching the index by sorting the list so that is why it's passing different data now). In short, I call the API, populate the list, setting up the provider too for the next page, and on click I list out the the information from the previous screen, but the problem is I display the same item always unless I sort the list. Here is the code:

Calling the API and displaying the list:

```
 var posts = <RideData>[];
  var streamController = StreamController<List<RideData>>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getRideStreamList();
    super.initState();
  }

  _getRideStreamList() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    var _vehicleStreamData = await APICalls.instance.getRides();

    var provider = Provider.of<RideStore>(context, listen: false);

    posts = await _vehicleStreamData
        .map<RideData>((e) => RideData.fromJson(e))
        .toList();

    streamController.add(posts);
    provider.setRideList(posts, notify: false);
  }

  bool isSwitched = true;
  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
    if (isSwitched == false) {
      posts.sort((k1, k2) => k1.rideId.compareTo(k2.rideId));
    } else {
      posts.sort((k1, k2) => k2.rideId.compareTo(k1.rideId));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                  child: Text('sort ascending'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      toggleSwitch(isSwitched = !isSwitched);
                    });
                  }),
              Container(
                height: 1000,
                child: StreamBuilder<List<RideData>>(
                    initialData: posts,
                    stream: streamController.stream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Ride #${snapshot.data[index].rideId}',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    textColor: Colors.blue[700],
                                    minWidth: 0,
                                    child: Text('View'),
                                    onPressed: () {
// here is where I pass the data to the RideInfo screen
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => RideInfo(
                                                    rideId: snapshot
                                                        .data[index].rideId,
                                                  )));
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '${snapshot.data[index].pickupTime}',
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${snapshot.data[index].jobArrived}',
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

After pressing the View button and passing the data to another screen (RideInfo):

```
class RideInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'ride_info_screen';
  String rideId;
  RideInfo({@required this.rideId});

  @override
  _RideInfoState createState() => _RideInfoState();
}

class _RideInfoState extends State<RideInfo> {
  String rideID = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      rideID = widget.rideId;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'Ride #$rideID',
          ),
        ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Consumer<RideStore>(
            builder: (context, rideStore, child) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 1,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        RideData rides = rideStore.getRideByIndex(index);
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "PICK UP",
                                  ),
// here I display the pickUpTime but it is always the same and I wanted to display the time based on the ID
                                  Text(
                                    '${rides.pickupTime}AM',
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The data (`pickUpTime` in this case) doesn't change when I press to see the View of a single item, but like I said, when I change the order of the list with the sort method, then I get the different data.
Here is the Provider model:

```
class RideStore extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<RideData> _rideList = [];

  List<RideData> get rideList => _rideList;

  setRideList(List<RideData> list, {bool notify = true}) {
    _rideList = list;
    if (notify) notifyListeners();
  }

  RideData getRideByIndex(int index) => _rideList[index];

  int get rideListLength => _rideList.length;
}
```

How do I display the correct information based on the ID from the List that I pressed and passed in the Ride Info screen so it doesn't give back always the same data? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending code is in `RideInfo`:

```
  ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        RideData rides = rideStore.getRideByIndex(index);
```

The `index` is always `1`, so you are always showing the first `RideData`. There are various options to fix it, e.g. pass the `index`, or even pass the `RideData`, to the `RideInfo` constructor:

```
class RideInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'ride_info_screen';
  String rideId;
  final int index;
  RideInfo({@required this.rideId, @required this.index, Key key})
      : super(key: key) {
```

and:

```
        RideData rides = rideStore.getRideByIndex(widget.index);
```

I have some additional comments on the code. Firstly, the `ListView` is serving no purpose in `RideInfo`, so remove it.

Secondly, there is no need to construct the `streamController` and to use `StreamBuilder` in the parent form. Your list is available in the `RideStore`. So your parent form could have:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = Provider.of<RideStore>(context).rideList;
    ...
          Container(
            height: 1000,
            child:
                // StreamBuilder<List<RideData>>(
                //     initialData: posts,
                //     stream: streamController.stream,
                //     builder: (context, snapshot) {
                //       return
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data.length,
```

I hope these comments help.

**Edit:**

It is simple to edit your code to use `FutureBuilder`. Firstly, make `_getRideStreamList` return the data it read:

```
  _getRideStreamList() async {
    ...
    return posts;
  }
```

Remove the call to `_getRideStreamList` in `initState` and wrap the `ListView` in the `FutureBuilder` that invokes `_getRideStreamList`:

```
          Container(
            height: 1000,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _getRideStreamList(),
              builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else {
                  var data = snapshot.data;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    ...
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

This displays the `CircularProgressIndicator` while waiting for the data.

Note that this is a quick hack - you do not want to read the data everytime that the widget rebuilds. So `_getRideStreamList` could check if the data has already been read and just return it rather than rereading.

Comment: First of all mate, I would like to thank you for the detailed answer, much appreciated! I passed the `index` in this case, I wasn't sure how to successfully pass the complete `Ride Data` to `Ride Info`. Second, I used `Stream Builder` without the `Provider` so I didn't had the chance to refactor it before posting, but thanks again for the heads up, I really do appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: No worries. You can pass your `RideData` to `RideInfo` on the constructor, just like any value: `RideData ride; RideInfo({@required RideData this.ride});`

Comment: As per your suggestion I removed the unnecessary code, now the problem is that I need to refresh my widget since the the `ListView.builder` renders the widget before the data is reached from the API, I tried with `FutureBuilder` and I used 'Provider' since I'm calling an API, but I got the same issue...